# How do you get monitor to shut off when screen is locked?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

When I lock my screen, the monitor does not shut off, even though the display is set to sleep after 10 minutes.  I suspect it is because one of the applications running is preventing sleep.  Is there a way to tell the mac to suspend the monitor in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Locking your screen and putting your display to sleep are two totally different things.  Locking your screen is preventing others from accessing your desktop and does not necessarily put your display to sleep.

There are a couple options for you to immediately put your display to sleep and lock the display:

**Keyboard Shortcut:**  If you want to put your display to sleep, use the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>^Control</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Power Button</kbd>.

**Hot Corners**.  You can also set a Hot Corner.  Just move your mouse to the desired corner and it will put your display to sleep.

[image]

The key here, to get the display to lock ***and*** go to sleep  is to make sure that you have your security settings set to require a password (from "immediately" to "8 hours").

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I know that screen lock and display sleep are two different things.  My display is set to sleep after 10 minutes, but sometimes does not, because an app is preventing it.  This doesn't make sense when the display is locked.